# Show that if A is an n-by-n real symmetric matrix with $A^k$=Id for some k$\ge$1. Then $A^2$=Id.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**My attempt**

Proof. We know that if $A^k$=id for some k$\ge$$1$, then A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \end{pmatrix} or $A^k$=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \end{pmatrix} for some k$>$$1$ by properties of matrix multiplication thus for k=2, we have that $A^2$=(id)(id)=(id), as claimed.

Note that id denotes the identity matrix.

I'm not sure whether my approach here is correct, but I argued that given the problem statement whereby $A^k$=id for some k at least 1, this means that k is at least 1 s.t. $A^1$=id holds? Hence if $A^1$=id, then by properties of matrix multiplication $A^2$=id. I may be interpreting this wrong, but my understanding is that the "OR" gate has 75% of the sample space available. In other words, if some k=1 is true and some k>1 is true, then using the fact that $A^1$=id, can we reason that $A^2$=id?

Comment: I don't think $A^k=I$ for some $k$, means $A=I$ or $A^2=I$, but it means that $A$ is diagonalizable

Comment: @Ihf. Sorry I made a mistake with the claim. The claim is actually that an n-by-n real symmetric matrix A with $A^k$=id for some k$\ge$1 implies that $A^2$=id.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symmetric matrix of finite order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2101469/symmetric-matrix-of-finite-order)

Comment: @Cameron Buie, that problem is intrinsically the same. However, I'm curious to know whether we can logically reason about this problem statement using my approach; that is, if for some k$\ge$1, then k could be at least 1?

Comment: @Karam: I'm afraid that won't work. Aside from symmetry, exactly the same things can be said about the matrix $A$ in my answer. Indeed, there is some $k\ge 1$ such that $A^k=I.$ However, it is not true that $k=1,$ nor that $k=2.$ You're effectively trying to make a probabilistic case that $k$ is likely to be $1$ or $2,$ but the "sample space" in this case is infinite, so that's not a well-justified claim.

Comment: You're right that if $k$ happens to equal $1$ or $2,$ then we can conclude that $A^2=I.$ However, what we must prove is that it is impossible to have the least such $k>2,$ which your argument doesn't do.

Comment: @Cameron Buie: I'm actually hoping you would clarify what it means when you say "some k$\ge$1". I've always thought of the greater than or equal to sign as "at least" in English.

Comment: @Cameron Buie, my understanding is that the problem statement says that "some k" is at least 1 for which $A^k$=id holds. Please let me know if this is not what the problem says.

Comment: @Karam I've edited my answer to try to address your confusion. Hopefully it clarifies things!

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: The source of your confusion seems to stem from the phrase "for some $k\geq1.$" You are correctly understanding the $k\geq 1$ part--this means $k$ could be $1,2,3,4,5,$ etc.--but it seems that you're thinking we're allowed to choose $k=1.$ This is absolutely false. For a simple example, consider $A=-I,$ so that $A^1\neq I,$ but $A^2=I.$

Rather, we must consider $k$ to be a completely arbitrary positive integer. To put it another way, we could consider this claim to be the following collection of related claims:

1. If $A$ is an $n\times n$ real symmetric matrix and $A^1=I,$ then $A^2=I.$
2. If $A$ is an $n\times n$ real symmetric matrix and $A^2=I,$ then $A^2=I.$
3. If $A$ is an $n\times n$ real symmetric matrix and $A^3=I,$ then $A^2=I.$
4. If $A$ is an $n\times n$ real symmetric matrix and $A^4=I,$ then $A^2=I.$
5. If $A$ is an $n\times n$ real symmetric matrix and $A^5=I,$ then $A^2=I.$
6. If $A$ is an $n\times n$ real symmetric matrix and $A^6=I,$ then $A^2=I.$

and so on.

---

**Added**: Let me give some terminology that might clear things up.

Given a square matrix $B,$ if there is no integer $k\ge 1$ for which $B^k=I,$ we say that $B$ has *infinite order*. Otherwise, we say that $B$ has *finite order*, and define *the order of* $B$ to be the smallest integer $k\ge 1$ for which $A^k=I.$

The claim states that if a real symmetric matrix $A$ has finite order, then it either has order $1$ (meaning that $A=I$) or has order $2$ (meaning that $A\neq I$ and $A^2=I$).

As a consequence of this, if I were to tell you I was thinking of a non-identity real symmetric matrix $A,$ you would immediately be able to conclude that $A^k\neq I$ whenever $k$ is a positive odd integer, despite knowing literally nothing else about my matrix. If I told you further that I calculated $A^{2640887552}$ and found out that it was the identity matrix, then (assuming I wasn't lying) you could conclude that $A^2=I,$ despite not knowing what my matrix is, or even what size it is! Moreover, you could conclude that $A^k=I$ for all positive even integers $k.$

Comment: Good catch. How do I edit the title? The claim is that if A is an n-by-n real symmetric matrix with A^k=id for some k$\ge$1. Then $A^2$=id.

Comment: There is an [Edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4143036/edit) button at the bottom of the post. Or you can just click that link.

Comment: But doesn't the problem say that "If $A^k$=I for some k$\ge$1, then..". So we can't use A=-I as an example here? Also, I'm thinking another approach would be to use induction?

Comment: Why can't we choose $k=1$ given that the problem statement says k is at least 1? That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Karam In fact, if $A=-I,$ then $A$ is real symmetric and it turns out that $A^k=I$ for all positive even numbers $k,$ in particular $k=2,$ so it's an example of a matrix like that which the claim describes. Icm glad you thought of induction! That's often a good plan when one needs to prove infinitely-many related claims. We can't choose the value of $k,$ because if we do, then we'll only be able to prove one of the numbered claims--namely, claim number $k$--but we're supposed to prove that $A^2=I$ *no matter what* positive integer $k$ is.

Comment: what doesn't make sense to me is the following: if the claim is, "$A^k$=Id for some $k\ge$1", then some k is at least 1 for which $A^k$=id? So if some k is at least 1 for which $A^k$=id, then $A^1$=id. Hence by definition of matrix multiplication $A^2$=id? But you're saying we can't say some k is at least 1, which means the greater than or equal to sign doesn't mean at least? Because if it does, then by the definition of matrix multiplication, we can prove claim number k+1, and so on. Let me know what you think.

Comment: It is **not** saying that $A^k=I$ for *every* $k\ge 1.$ Rather, it is saying that there is a positive integer $k$ for which $A^k=I,$ but it is not telling us what that integer is. Again, for an example that shows we cannot simply assume that $k=1,$ consider the example $A=-I.$ Note in particular that $A^1\neq I.$ However, $A^4=I,$ so there is a $k\ge 1$ such that $A^k=I.$ By the claim (or simple calculation), we can conclude that $A^2=I.$ I will adjust my answer once more to try to clarify.